# delete directory older than 7 days

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

I have backup files created daily in its own directory:

```
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
2020-04-03
```

so on

How can I write a code to delete older directory and its content. I have below code so far, it's deleting the directory but it's not smart enough. Because if I copy files in the directory to another another directory the modified date will change:

```
find ~/delete/* -type d -ctime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: If it is an option to delete the directories based on their name then you would be protected against those copy mtime problems.

Comment: I don't understand why you would copy backups without option `-p` or `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the directories by their names with `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
date=$(date -d '-7 day' '+%F')
for path in ~/delete/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]; do
  if [[ -d $path && ${path##*/} < $date ]]; then
    echo rm -rf "$path"
  fi
done
```

This loops over the pathnames matching the YYYY-MM-DD pattern and skips non-directories and directories
whose names don't sort lexicographically before the current date - 7 days.

With `nullglob` enabled the pathname pattern expands to a null string if there are no matching files/directories 
and the code inside the loop is not executed.

Remove the `echo` if the output looks as intended and run the script again to really delete those directories.

Comment: Thanks for the script. Another question what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The ctime and mtime timestamps change if you copy files into a directory or if you change ownership/permissions (ctime) as you already noticed. Note that ctime stands for _change_ time and not _create_ time.

Comment: Thank you Freddy!

Comment: Please note that `ctime` refers to the inode metadata and not the file content. `ctime` is updated on operations such as `chmod file`, whereas `mtime` is updated on operations such as `echo more >> file`. There is rarely a file creation (birth) time.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is a bit misleading since you cannot actually use timestamps, and have to trust the names.

A possible solution

```
keepAfter=$(date -d '-6 days' +'%F')
for d in */
do 
    [[ "$d" < "$keepAfter"/ ]] && echo rm -rf $d 
done
```

Remove the `echo` when happy with the results

Comment: can you explain your code? I tried for d in ~/ instead of */ but it doesn't find any directories.

Comment: The code expects to be run with your  `~/delete/` as the CWD (ie, `cd  ~/delete/` first).

Comment: i used ~/delete/ as the CWD but it still doesn't work but if i keep */ it does work.  for d in ~/delete

Comment: `for d in ~/delete` runs the loop once with `/home/{your id}/delete` and so compares `/home/{your id}/delete` directory against the date. `for d in */` runs the loop once for each subdirectory of the CWD... Freddy's solution is similar but the loop has a complete path to each subdirectory so the path has to be removed before being compared to a date.

Comment: xenoid, thank you for the script and your explanation, i appreciated. Have a great day sir.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
d=/path/to/deleted;
printf '%s\n' $d/*/ | awk -v upTo="$d/$(date -d '-6 days' +%F)" '$0<=upTo {print}' | xargs rm -r
```

In slo-mo:

- `printf '%s\n' $d/*/` generates a stream where each line is a subdirectory of `/path/to/deleted` (this line contains a full path: `/path/to/deleted/2020-04-12`)
- this is passed to `awk` with

  - `-v upTo="$d/$(date -d '-6 days' +%F)"`: creates an `upTo` variable which is the most recent directory to erase (with full path: `/path/to/deleted/2020-04-12`)
  - `'$0<=upTo {print}'` is a `awk` program that only prints out the input lines that are lexicographically smaller or equal to the `upTo` contents, so this filters out the directories after the break date.
- `xargs rm -r` applies `rm -r` to all lines from stdin (ie, the directories that were not filtered out)

The advantage of this code is that there is no shell loop, and `rm` is likely called only once for all the directories.

If you `cd /path/to/deleted` first, the code is a bit simpler (you no longer need the `$d` variable).

```
printf '%s\n' */ | awk -v upTo="$(date -d '-6 days' +%F)" '$0<=upTo {print}' | xargs rm -r
```